# Workflow using REST API returns different result from browser

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365, designer-workflow

In SP Online I have the following problem:

The query: `https://mysite/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:My content Type'`

if I query by the content-type using the browser I get the

```
d/query/PrimaryQueryResult/RelevantResults/RowCount
```

equals **4**, but if I query through a `Call Web Service Action` from Workflow on Sharepoint Design.

using the same URL, RequestHeaders beeing a dictionary with both Accept and Content-Type being initialized with `application/json;odata=verbose` parameter, it is not returning the same data, is actually returning **0** and no elements.

I am just trying to count the number of elements from a certain content type using the workflow, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because of a permission problem.

Workflow runs under an App identity. That App identity has only access to the current sub-site.
Your search request probably returns 4 results when considering all your sites and if you have access to all results...
However, when called from a WF, it gets only result the WF has access to, so only results from the current sub-site, so maybe 0 result...

One option would be to configure the workflow to use App-only permissions (+ site collection Full Control) and set your "Call a Web service" action from an "App stage". You'll then get results from the entire site collection (but still not from *all* site collections :()

Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx) that explains you how to allow your WF to use App-only permissions and add an App stage in it.
Note that to allow entire Site collection, you need to change `http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web` at step #7 to `http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/sitecollection` (as seen in section "Eventual Resolution" of http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2014/06/19/gotcha-on-sharepoint-designer-workflows-in-app-step/).